# how to use for of loop, resulting an array as an output

Tags: javascript, for-loop, capitalize, for-of-loop

I want to capitalize the days in the array named 'days' and get the result in an array form only by calling 'console.log(days)'
Please see below :
Can anybody help me finish up code in the the block of for of loop?

edit(summary) : 
I questioned this to know the reason why the value of the each 'day' does not get changed in this case. and Suren Srapyan has provided a great answer to this :
'You are getting the copy of each item in the loop. So day is only a copy of the item's value and changing it to have another value will not change the item in the array.'

```
let days = ['sunday', 'monday', 'tuesday', 'wednesday', 'thursday', 'friday', 'saturday'];

for (day of days) {
    day = day[0].toUpperCase() + day.slice(1);
    // your code goes here

}
console.log(days);
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`for of` is not like to any simple loop. Under it is another construction.

You are getting the copy of each item in the loop. So `day` is only a **copy** of the **item's value** and changing it to have another value will not change the item in the array.

Here is what going under the `for of` loop.

```js
let days = ['sunday', 'monday', 'tuesday', 'wednesday', 'thursday', 'friday', 'saturday'];

const iterator = days[Symbol.iterator]();
let item = iterator.next();

while(!item.done) {
    console.log(item.value);
    item = iterator.next();
}
```

Above code shows that `for of` loop is only for **readonly purposes**

You can use [**Array#map**](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/map) function for it

```js
let days = ['sunday', 'monday', 'tuesday', 'wednesday', 'thursday', 'friday', 'saturday'];

days = days.map(day => day[0].toUpperCase() + day.slice(1));

console.log(days);
```

Answer (score 0):

You can also use forEach loop to do the task.

```
days.forEach(function(item, index, array) {
      array[index] = item[0].toUpperCase() + item.slice(1)
});
console.log(days);
```

Answer (score 0):

> you can also use reduce method of array

```js
let days = ['sunday', 'monday', 'tuesday', 'wednesday', 'thursday', 'friday', 'saturday'];

let result = days.reduce((r,a)=>r.concat(a.charAt(0).toLocaleUpperCase()+a.slice(1)),[]);

console.log(result)
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this one and I think It will help

```
const days = ['sunday', 'monday', 'tuesday', 'wednesday', 'thursday', 'friday', 'saturday'];

for (let day of days){ 

    let firstLetter= day.substr(0,1)
    let otherLetters=day.substr(1)
    console.log(firstLetter.toUpperCase().concat(otherLetters));

}
```